# Basis of a 3x3 eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm currently in the middle of a question where I'm given a 3x3 matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 7 & 0\\
4 & 8 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$

and have been asked to find the characteristic polynomial, eigenvalue and eigenvector/eigenspace when $\lambda = 3$

the aswer I got is $$ \left(\begin{array}{r}
\frac14\\
\frac18\\
1 
\end{array}\right) $$

The question then asks to find the basis of this eigenspace, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector you give is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 3$. The eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 3$ is the subvectorspace generated by this vector, so all scalar multiples of this vector.

A basis of this eigenspace is for example this very vector (yet any other non-zero multiple of it would work too).

Comment: So I don't do anything with it?

Comment: Yes, there is no need for further calculation. What you likely should do though is write down what the eigenspace is, as explained  in this and the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenspace is the set $E=\{kv_3\mid k\in\Bbb R\}$ where the eigenvector: 
$$v_3=\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{8}\\1\end{array}\right),$$ 
is performing as a base vector for $E$.